# Geolocator hanging on WP8, working on 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation

Geolocator seems to simply not work on WP8 when it should. (But for some strange reason works perfectly fine on 8.1)... I'm in optimal conditions - LTE, FiOS Wifi... No obstructions. No reason why it shouldn't work. However, it seems to just hang and never return the current location or even an exeption.

I have tried to disable the reverse geocode and it does not work. I've narrowed it down to being the actual service that gets the location (Geolocator or GeoPosition)

ID_CAP_LOCATION is enabled. Phone location services are enabled. I'm targeting WP8.

Code:

```
private async void getlocation()
        {
            try
            {
                Geolocator gl = new Geolocator(); gl.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;

                Geoposition geoposition = await gl.GetGeopositionAsync(maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                latitude = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString(); longitude = geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();

                //Location to physical address
                List<MapLocation> locations;
                ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
                query.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude, geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude);

                //Set address to tecxtblock
                query.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    locations = e.Result as List<MapLocation>;
                    address = locations[0].Information.Address.City.ToString();
                    ts.Center = new GeoCoordinate(geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude, geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude);
                    ts.ZoomLevel = 7;
                    location.Text = address.ToUpper(); //Location

                    //Successful, now get weather for current location
                    getforecast();
                };
                query.QueryAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Location services appear to be turned off. To use Atmosphere, turn location services on.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered issues on WP8 with background tracking where it would only update the the position when the app was bought to the foreground. Very confusing as I knew it was working on other devices without issue.

In the end I simply un-installed the app completely and re-installed, this solved the issue. Just in case you haven't tried it - just completely remove the app and re-install / re-deploy using Visual Studio. Issue might resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The same code works in 8.1 but does not in 8.0

I was able to make it work when i called the function from a button click instead of the constructor of the Page or in Page_loaded event.